# how to pass value to javascript through clicking <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, mouseevent

I have the following Unordered List which has been dynamically populated from database through JQuery .ajax, with a few list items which are names of the products.

```
<ul id="here">
<li>Product 1</li>
<li>Product 1</li>
<li>Product 1</li>
<li>Product 1</li>
<li>Product 1</li>
</ul>
```

I can hover over these through mouse events in css with the following code

```
li:hover {background: #ccc; cursor: pointer;}
```

The javascript code for populating the `<li>` is as follows:

```
var pr= [Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, Product5];
for (var option in pr){
var newLi = document.createElement("li");
newLi.innerHTML=pr[option];
$("#here").append(newLi);}
```

But I want to pass the Product Name inside of the `<li>` element to another input element through Javascript or JQuery when that `<li>` element is clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: show your js code?

Comment: @ Fast Snail 
The JS code has been shared above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I see you are using jQuery, you can bind the ul's "click" event like so:

```
$("#here").on("click", "li", function(evt) {
   $("#your_Input_Id").val(evt.target.innerHTML);
});
```

Example at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bkbtert9/

Answer (score 1):

Since li are being created dynamically you need to use event delegation as `<li>` won't be on dom when code is executed. This example code should work for you. Try it:

```
var clickLiData = "";
$("#here").on("click","li",function()
{
 clickLiData = $(this).html();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

assume the targeted input is text.

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
```

so here is the javascript for the desired result.

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $item = $(this).html();
    $("#text").val($item);
});
```